# General way to find Nash equilibrium in continuous game

Tags: calculus-of-variations, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I'm really interesting how to find Nash equilibrium in a continuous game with two players in the general case.

Let's consider a game with continuous utility functions $F_1, F_2 : [0, 1] \times [0, 1] \to [0, 1] $. 
Let's say that each player has probability density function over all possible actions $f_1, f_2 : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}_+$ and $\int{f_i(x)\,dx} = 1$.

For example, the first player has expected payoff:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} f_1(x)\,f_2(y)\,F_1(x, y)\,dy\,dx$$

I think it's possible to use Lagrange multipliers to set constrains on $\int{f_i(x)\,dx}$ and use Euler Lagrange equation to find stationary point of expected payoff for both players.

However, I don't have any ideas how to use both methods in this case. Is there any way to write equations over $f_1$ and $f_2$ to find Nash equilibrium?

I'd like to hear any ideas on this topic.